# How to monitor the percentage progress of a file upload in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload, google-chrome-devtools, progress-bar

While troubleshooting a bug in a HTML form I noticed that Google Chrome no longer displays the file upload progress indicator that was present in older versions.

[image: Screenshot of Google Chrome showing text Uploading (81%)...]

I thought that the DevTools Network tab did display the progress of the request, but it seems that is not the case. It displays information when the request is initialized and when it is finished, but no progress in between.

I would like to see the progress as a percentage in Chrome, like how it was available previously. Using BrowserStack to test lots of older versions, it seems that it stopped working in Chrome 91. I have checked 6 other browsers too and none of them seem to display it.

I am uploading files that take about 10 minutes. Is there any way to see the progress?

(Note: I am not looking to modify the page, adding JavaScript for example. Unless there is something simple that I could paste in the Console.)